# How to send a parameter from the controller to a model with a number of different parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller is like this :

```
function a()
{
    ...
    $notification = $this->notification_model->get_notification($session['customer_id'], 10);
    ...
}

function b()
{
    ...
    $new_notification = $this->notification_model->get_notification($session['customer_id'], 1, "notification_new");
    ...
}
```

My model is like this :

```
function get_notification($customer_id, $limit, $is_notif)
{
    ...
}
```

The number of parameters passed :

In function a : 2 parameter

In function b : 3 parameter

In function(model) : 3 parameter

> When executed, there exist error like this : Message: Missing
>   argument 3 for....

This is because different parameters

Any soluton to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model function you can set the third parameter default value as null in function a()

```
function get_notification($customer_id, $limit, $is_notif=null)
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1):

Make function like this

```
function get_notification($customer_id, $limit, $is_notif=NULL)
{

}
```

hopes help you.....